# Cannot delete from aspnet_Users or AspNetUsers?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, localdb

I have a database setup using aspnet_regsql and I am using the web forms template included with visual studio 2013. I am trying to delete from aspnet_Users and AspNetUsers. However, I need to use a stored procedure since I am deleting from two different tables. I can get the user deleted from AspNetUsers but not aspnet_Users. Am I doing something wrong in my stored procedure for this to not work?

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteAllUserReferences]
        @UserName  NVARCHAR(256),
        @Id  NVARCHAR(128),
        @Role NVARCHAR(256),
        @RowsAffected int OUTPUT
    AS BEGIN TRY
        SET NOCOUNT ON                                                 
        SET XACT_ABORT ON  
        EXEC aspnet_Users_DeleteUser 'mainwebsite',@UserName,15,@RowsAffected output
       BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DELETE FROM [AspNetUsers] WHERE Id = @Id
       COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
       IF @@trancount > 0 
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION                        
       EXEC error_handler_sp                                          
       RETURN 55555 

    END CATCH

    RETURN 0
```

Note: aspnet_Users_DeleteUser has not executed in asp.net when I call it but does manually from the SQL server explorer in visual studio. Edit: I forgot the error handler below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE error_handler_sp AS

DECLARE @errmsg   nvarchar(2048),
        @severity tinyint,
        @state    tinyint,
        @errno    int,
        @proc     sysname,
        @lineno   int

SELECT @errmsg = error_message(), @severity = error_severity(),   -- 10
       @state  = error_state(), @errno = error_number(),
       @proc   = error_procedure(), @lineno = error_line()

IF @errmsg NOT LIKE '***%'                                        -- 11  
BEGIN 
   SELECT @errmsg = '*** ' + coalesce(quotename(@proc), '<dynamic SQL>') + 
                    ', ' + ltrim(str(@lineno)) + '. Errno ' + 
                    ltrim(str(@errno)) + ': ' + @errmsg
   RAISERROR(@errmsg, @severity, @state)
END
ELSE
   RAISERROR(@errmsg, @severity, @state)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I solved this. It turns out during deletion I have to have UserName in the DataKeyValues property in the listview in order to delete the user from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add the UserName field to DataKeyNames property of the listview and it works!